# application-context.xml problem for Spring ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, spring, spring-actionscript

```
content  of The application-content.xml is 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springactionscript.org/schema/objects"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springactionscript.org/schema/objects
                              http://www.springactionscript.org/schema/objects/spring-actionscript-objects-1.0.xsd">

  <property file="strings.properties" />

  <object id="string1" class="String"/>
  <object id="string2" class="String"/>
  <object id="nlslzf" class="com.sgb.model.MyClass"/>  

 </objects>
```

content of strings.properties is:

```
s1=Firststring
s2=Secondstring
```

but error:

```
Main Thread (Suspended: Error: An object definition for 'string1' was not found.)   
                org.springextensions.actionscript.ioc.factory.support::AbstractObjectFactory/getObject  
                SpringActionScript/test 
                SpringActionScript/onCreationComplete   
                SpringActionScript/___SpringActionScript_Application1_creationComplete  
                flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction [no source] 
                mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent  
                mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized    
                mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation    
                Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply [no source]   
                mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher2   
                mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher2   
                mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher
```

i can run normal if removed the '' 
why it is? springactionscript bug?

Comment: Please edit this. Seperate the code from the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed 'smell' like a Spring Actionscript bug.
Please file a bug report for this in our JIRA system:

[SpringAS JIRA](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SESPRINGACTIONSCRIPTAS)

If you can, add a sample project that demonstrates the bug, that way we'll be able to track down the issue easier and faster.